# How to save the modifications of a column in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, save

I'm coding a website where users can add concerts/events and other users can modify the informations provided for every concert/event added on the website.

I want to save every modification that has been made and the user that made the modification. For instance there is this functionnality on Wikipedia where every article has saves of every modification made and the user who made it.

For now, I just save the name of the user who made the last modification(s), and the modifications aren't saved: when a modification is made it will just overwrite the previous value of the corresponding column.

You can see under the current state of the tables I'm talking about. One for concerts with different informations: artist, date of the event, hour, links related to the event etc...
and another one for users.

[Current sql tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pwKR.png)

I think a first step would to create separate tables for every element of a concert that can be modified, with 2 foreign keys (one linked to user, one linked to concert) plus the value of the element. But still, if a modification is made I still don't know how to save the previous value and previous user.

I've thought of puting values inside an array but I don't know if this is possible in SQL and if this is the best solution.

Thanks for reading/helping

Answer (score 0):

You should add a column that mark the create/update time to the concert table.
Then create a new history table (same schema of concert) for storing concert changes.

When a user **edit** a concert:

- **Save** the current state of concert content to the **history table**.
- **Update** the new change to the **concert table** with the user_id of the user who perform this action

That's it! When you want to list the changes history, just query the history table!

If you want to log the delete operations as well, add another column and mark the end period of each version (a little bit more complex)

Comment: thanks, I figured it out and did as you said. I could have found the solution by myself but yeah I got mind stuck and couldn't see this easy solution.